# Efficient way to convert long to String in Java

Tags: java

I've been using

```
long a = 123456789;
String b = a+"";
```

to convert a `long` value (or `int`) to `String`, or in this perspective, treat it as String. My question is, is it ok to do this? Are there any negative impact?

And is there any difference in using `String.valueOf()` vs `Long.toString()`?

Thanks

Comment: `String b = a.toString();`. Seriously, read the javadoc. That's something you should figure out by yourself.

Comment: The docs say that `String.valueOf(long)` is the same as `Long.toString(long)`. And indeed if you open the first, it shows a call to the second. So calling the second directly is "more efficient" since you leave out the intermediate call.

Comment: You can't use a.toString() due to the fact, toString is used on objects.

Comment: @xenteros OP edited `Long` to `long`. So when @JKNizet made the comment, his statement for `String b = a.toString();` was correct.

Comment: Isn't there any error or warning when you declare `Long a = 123456789;`, because java accepts `Long` with a terminating `L` like `123456789L`

Comment: @JBNizet I'm sorry, I meant the primitive data type long.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, I meant the primitive data type "long" not "Long"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is ok to do this as recent JVM will likely reduce it to:

```
String b = String.valueOf(a);
```

As for negatives, it is not good Java coding style as there is ambiguity. If **a** was **null**, would **b = "null"**? or will an NPE be thrown? You know the answer with experience, but this should be obvious to all readers of your code.

Comment: That's not correct. The java compiler will replace this with a StringBuilder.
new StringBuilder().append(a).append("").toString()

Answer (score 4):

First, your code doesn't compile - you have to append an `L` after the literal:

```
Long a = 123456789L;
```

`String.valueOf()` and `Long.toString()` methods both have a primitive `long` as a parameter, but since `a` is an wrapper (`Long`), you can just use the `Object#toString()` method:

```
String b = a.toString();
```

If `a`, however, is a primitive (`long`), both `String.valueOf()` and `Long.toString()` will do the same, so it's a matter of preference which one to use.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant a primitive data type long. I just did that for an example, I'll edit it anyway. So is it ok to concatenate it that way??